# Creating Evernote Note from the command line

Tags: evernote

Is there a way to create a Evernote note from the command line? At best I would like to be able to edit the same note later via the command line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out http://geeknote.me/.

Geeknote is a command line tool for manipulating evernote. You can creating notes, list notebook, search notebooks etc.

I also has a feature to sync files a directory of text files with evernote.

Comment: Note that it's note Windows compatible.

Comment: @Isaac Kleinman, (assuming you mean not) I don't think that is correct. Its written in python, so I see no reason why it should not run on windows.

Comment: Freudian slip ;)

Comment: The README says "Geeknote is a command line client for Evernote that can be use on Linux, FreeBSD and OS X" but I guess perhaps that means "_even_ on Linux, FreeBSD and OS X"?

Comment: Next Paragraph: "Geeknote is written in Python, so you can use the open source package anywhere you have Python, even in Windows if you like."..

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Evernote Scripting command (ENScript).  I have the following in a batch file for adding a short note:

`echo %* | c:\PROGRA~2\EVERNOTE\EVERNOTE\ENSCRIPT.EXE createNote /i %1 /t SHORTNOTE`

This will create a note with the first parameter being the title, and the title and the remaining parameters go into the note.